# Can a bmp image be 16bit depth?

Tags: color-conversion, image-quality, pixel, bitmap, bit

I'm trying to create a watchface for my wristband and the only form of image I'm supposed to play with is a bmp image, 16bit depth, 300 KB size or lower. It seems impossible to combine these 3, Please help. Thank you!

" If this layer is a background layer, the background format is only supported in BMP -- Advanced mode -- 16-bit --R5G6B5 -- width and height must be even " that's the specification.

Comment: The problem is that 16 bit depth can mean 2 distinctly different things. It can mean that the color is 16 bit in total or 16 bit per channel.

Comment: A pure guess. If 16 bit in total, it's probably an indexed colour bmp. So, like a gif, the fewer indexed colours you use, the lower the file size can be.

Comment: Post the link for the specification you are asking for. IMHO there is no way someone is asking weird formats. So probably you are misreading something.

Comment: " If this layer is a background layer, the background format is only supported in BMP -- Advanced mode -- 16-bit --R5G6B5 -- width and height must be even " that's the specification.

Answer (score 0):

Oh. Ok. Your hardware is asking for a "raw" raster image because it does not want to decode it (JPG or PNG files need to be decoded). This is common on hardware that can afford a decent memory but has a small processor.

It is asking indeed for a 16-bit overall file, that is lighter than a full 24-bit one and has more color options than an indexed 8-bit file.

You can prepare your file on any application and export it on Gimp.

1. File > Export
2. On the dialog box, type the filename and manually type the .bmp extension.
3. When you select the BMP extension and use the Advanced options, you can choose the file subformat.

[image]

As the image is RAW (uncompressed), this means that the only way to have the 300kb weight limit is to play with the pixel dimensions.

It would be an image of roughly 390x390px if it is square.

See the screen resolution of your device for an exact fit.

Comment: Oh, thank you so much Rafael, it worked!